# Port forwarding through VPN (PPTP)

Tags: networking, router, vpn, port-forwarding, pptp

I want to forward ports trough VPN tunnel PPTP that has been set up using windows only, on router i just forwarded port 1723 (PPTP) and port desired to be available from the internet.

The server is supposed to be located on the VPN Client. On The router of VPN Server WAN i forwarded the desired port to 192.168.0.3 or 192.168.0.100 and neither have worked. The purpose of this idea is that the VPN client is behind a NAT that i cannot currently disable.

Here is the quick horrible schematic of my network:

[image]

Edit: Additional info: The game server is to be available trough VPN server WAN without VPN. VPN will be connected for administration only.

Edit2: The problem is probably about router that the VPN Server is behind not seeing VPN client, that's why I cannot forward ports. Any ideas?

Comment: First of all you are in really big danger if you using PPTP. Second it really unclear what you want.  VPN tunnel is just the same as you plug computer to a real ethernet. You don't need to forward anything, both computers are in the same subnet, so they should see each other and can use resources on both sides if permissions allow it

Comment: @Alex I know that this protocol is not secure, nothing sensitive is being transmitted trough it. It' supposed to be game server. The purpose is to make server active on VPN client to be available trough VPN Server WAN because of the NAT on VPN client that cannot be disabled. I didn't want to use openvpn because it requires installation from what i know and i wanted it to be available more out of the box on foreign computers. They say that strong encryption used in it could also slow down response times which are crucial in case of games server.